# How to export saved FTP password from GNOME Commander?

Tags: gnome, password, ftp, password-recovery

I am migrating to another computer. And I need saved FTP passwords from Gnome Commander which I was using for the connection. Where should I search for these password?

Comment: It depends on where you stored them (gnome commander can be set up to use the keyring ;-) ) but I assume you want the default location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gnome-commander.1.html):

```
~/.gnome-commander/connections
List of remote connections (see "Connections" menu).
```

This is the non-secure method since it hold passwords in [plain text](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/gnome-commander-security-issue-888751/#post4397922).

Comment: yes! It worked! You are my life savior :)